# A lighthouse problem (Calculus). Is the problem as easy as it seems?

Tags: calculus

The problem is supposed to be a modified version of the lighthouse problem.

Description:

A lighthouse (in point N) is located 4 km away from the shore at sea. A bar is located on the shoreline, 4 km away from point W. Point W is located on the shore such that it is the shortest and the most direct path from the lighthouse to the shore. The shoreline is perpendicular to WN. 
We know that a man who is now in the lighthouse wants to go the bar. Also, we know that he rows at the rate of 4 km/h and walks at the rate of 5 km/h. What path should the man choose in order to get to the bar in shortest period of time?

My question is: is the problem as easily solvable as I understand? It seems that no knowledge of calculus is needed to solve it. Or I am missing something?

My solution: we get a triangle which has a perpendicular. We calculate NK, where K is the bar and N is the lighthouse. So now we have 2 paths: NK and NWK. We use the rowing and walking rates to calculate how much time each path will take. Then we compare the results.

As a result, the shortest path is rowing straight from the lighthouse to the bar.

Comment: We don't know what you understand, so can you edit your question to include your proposed solution? My opinion is that this is a calculus question, but there is often more than one way to solve something.

Comment: Do you know how to derive Snell's law? If you find that trivial, so is this.

Comment: In this case, a straight line solution isn't necessarily the best because he walks faster than he rows.

Comment: There are more than two paths. He can row to any point on the shore, not just to W or directly to the bar.

Comment: There are problems similar to this one that have two-phase solutions (row part of the way and walk part of the way). They have different numbers, however; for example, the bar might be further away, or the lighthouse might be closer to the shore, or the ratio of walking to rowing speeds might be greater. This makes me wonder if the person who set the numbers for this problem made a typo somewhere; for example, perhaps one of the "4 km" numbers was supposed to be something else.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I forgot to take that into account. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The straight line solution is the correct solution. Here is why.

He will row along some straight line path to the shore and land at a point $x$ which is between $0$ and $4$ kilometers from the bar. We want to minimize the total time it takes. The total time will consist of his time on the water and his time on the shore. Making use of the distance formula $d=rt$, where $d$ is distance, $r$ is rate and $t$ is time, and the fact that the total is the sum of its parts, we get

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{16+x^2}}{4}+\frac{4-x}{5}$$ as the total time.

The first term in the sum is the time on the water and the second term represents the time on land.

Taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and setting it to $0$  gives $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{x}{4\sqrt{16+x^2}}-\frac{1}{5}=0\implies x=\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{16+x^2}\implies x^2=\frac{16}{25}(16+x^2)\implies x^2=\frac{256}{9}$$ which gives $x=\frac{16}{3}$

But $\frac{16}{3}\gt 5$ and this expression only works for $x$ between $0$ and $4$.

Moreover, for $x$ between $0$ and $4$, $\frac{dt}{dx}\lt 0$ which means more $x$, less time. Therefore, the minimum time occurs when $x=4$ and the minimum time is $t=\sqrt{2}$ which is what you originally had.

Answer (score -1):

You are right.Walking 8 km at 5 kph takes 1.6 hrs.Rowing $4\sqrt 2$ km at $4$ kph takes $\sqrt 2$ hrs. And $\sqrt 2<1.6 \iff 2<1.6^2=2.56$. And no calculus.Which is good because he should not drink and calculus.

Comment: Don't drink and derive? (More seriously: what about the other paths, such as walk a bit and row a bit? I think you **do** want some calculus.)

Comment: Didn't think of a walk/row mix. probably because most of us wouldn't actually do that.If it's supposed to be a calculus problem,yes. He could carry the boat  or tow it beside the path, presumably at 5kph.